# SASS Directory won't change

Tags: css, sass

I keep trying to run `sass --watch scss:css` on a directory and unfortunately, the scss files are not compiling.

SASS does confirm that it's watching for changes, but I've noticed that it is looking in my Program Files directory.

[image]

My project with the actual SCSS and CSS files is in my `C/username/documents/project/assets` directory. If I try to enter that path explicitly in the `sass --watch` command, I get an error message.

How can I specify the correct directory so SASS will stop trying to compile my files in `Program Files`?

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure your sass is working well and you can try below option for compiling into different folder.

sass --watch input-dir:output-dir